# How to initialize empty char positions in an C++ array?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ Person class with a char array to manage the name (I cannot use string or vector or other libraries):

```
Person::Person() : name{ new char[100]{"DEFAULT"} }
{}
```

The Person has a method to print its name:

```
void Person::print() {
    int i = 0;
    for (const char* c = name; *c != '\0'; c++) {
        cout << *c;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

When creating a person and printing it's name, the chars after the name are also printed and obviously are meaningless values:

```
int main() {

    Person me("Superman");
    me.print();

}
```

[image]

Should `"Superman"` not at an implicit termination character?

---

Edit:

Here's the full Person class:

```
Person::Person() : name{ new char[100]{"DEFAULT"} }
{}

Person::Person(const char* c) : name{ new char[100] }
{
    int i = 0;
    for (const char* l = c; *l != '\0'; l++) {
        name[i] = *l;
        i++;
    }
}

Person::Person(const Person& person) : name{ new char[100] }
{
    int i = 0;
    for (const char* l = person.name; *l != '\0'; l++) {
        name[i] = *l;
        i++;
    }
}

Person::~Person()
{
    delete[] name;
}

void Person::print() {
    int i = 0;
    for (const char* c = name; *c != '\0'; c++) {
        cout << *c;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code shown, but likely in the constructor of `Person` that takes a string as a parameter.

Comment: Added the full class.. I'd thought the problem was in the print method

Comment: `Person(const char* c)` doesn't copy the terminating `\0` character from `c` to `name`. But `print()` expects it to be present.

Comment: *"I cannot use string or vector"*. So writing your own is an option.

Answer (score 0):

> How to initialize empty char positions in an C++ array?

There is no such thing as an "empty" position in an array.

What you need to do is add the terminating null character to the string. Simplest solution is to initially value initialise the array:

```
Person::Person(const char* c) : name{ new char[100]() }
```

P.S. Bare owning pointers should be avoided.